# How to respond automaticly with properties file to a yeoman prompt

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

When i run a app generator many question is ask by the prompt.
How can i run the "yo" command with, for example, a file with the answers for generate the app automatically without user interaction ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yeoman supports options and arguments http://yeoman.io/authoring/user-interactions.html

You can skip prompts when an option is provided instead. But this needs to be done manually by the generator author at the moment.

You can check the source code of generator-node and see how it is done over there: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-node/blob/master/generators/app/index.js

Answer (score 0):

A custom adapter can be used to provide answers to questions. This does require creating a new executable though, as the `yo` command does not support custom adapters.

Find an example of an adapter that answers questions at https://github.com/OctopusSamples/content-team-apps/blob/main/js/octopus-template-generator/src/domain/yeoman/adapter.ts.